# Pass complex javascript object configuration(data and functions) from json string

Tags: javascript, json, metaprogramming

I have a javascript that has a bunch of parameters and functions inside of it.

```
 ctrl.kendoGrid({
 dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "odata/CodeView",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        update: {
            url: function (data) {
                return "api/CodeMapUpdate/" + data.CODE_MAP_ID;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            complete: function (e) {
                ctrl.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                if (e.status == 201) {
                    logger.log("Record Updated: Record ID = " + e.responseJSON, null, null, true);
                } else {
                    logger.logError(" Save failed " + e.responseJSON.ExceptionMessage, null, null, true);
                }

            }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: function (data) {
                return "api/CodeMapDelete/" + data.CODE_MAP_ID;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function () {
                ctrl.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            }
        },
        create: {
            url: "api/CodeMapCreate",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (e) {
                ctrl.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sort({
                    field: "CODE_MAP_ID",
                    dir: "desc"
                });
                ctrl.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
                if (e.status == 201) {
                    logger.log("Record Created: Record ID = " + e.responseJSON, null, null, true);
                } else {
                    logger.logError(" Save failed " + e.responseJSON.ExceptionMessage, null, null, true);
                }

            }
        },
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            return data.value;
        },
        total: function (data) {
            return data["odata.count"];

        },
        model: {
            id: "CODE_MAP_ID",
            fields: {
                CODE_MAP_ID: {
                    editable: false,
                    type: "number"
                },
                CODE_NAME: {
                    type: "string",
                    validation: {
                        title: "Required Field",
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                L_NAME: {
                    type: "string",
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                CODE_DATE: {
                    field: "CODE_DATE",
                    type: "date",
                    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    },
    change: function () {

    },
    //batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: {
        field: "CODE_MAP_ID",
        dir: "desc"
    }
    //autoSync: true
} })
```

I am trying to save the entire "dataSource" object as a variable and retrieve it at runtime with ajax.
I am able to do this with eval ("(" + dataSource + ")") but any included functions are no longer executing.

Any idea on a strategy to store/retrieve this type of an object to/from JSON?

Comment: Function.prototype.toJSON=Function.toString; , revive on parse() using regexp to validate.

Comment: can you elaborate on this please, maybe some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple demo of how to use the 2nd param to JSON.parse to recover stored functions:

```
var ob={a:1, b:false, c: function(a){ return a * a;} };//a sample object

Function.prototype.toJSON=Function.toString; //extend JSON to cover Functions

var str=JSON.stringify(ob, null, "\t"); //turn sample object into a string:
/* str =={
    "a": 1,
    "b": false,
    "c": "function (a){return a*a;}"
}  */


//now turn the string back into an object, using a reviver to re-parse methods:
var ob2=JSON.parse(str, function(a,b){
  if(b.match && b.match(/^function[\w\W]+\}$/)){ b=eval("b=0||"+b); }
  return b;
});


var n=5;    //let's try the method using a number
var n2=ob2.c(5); //apply the method to the number
alert(n2); // shows: 25, the number times itself, verifying that the function works
```

You might want to be a litle stricter about what you send to eval, maybe use a key schema in addition to matching properties that simply look like functions. you can beef-up the regexp to be a little stricter, but for this quick demo of the JSON.parse() parameter, it all works just fine.

In this case, since you are collecting the properties of the JSON, there's no chance of running into the security issues that eval() use can facilitate. Those problems stem from sending one user's input to another user without filtering, not when you jump-start code the client itself produced last time...